# If I buy a property in an underage dependent's name am I exempt from capital gains (losses) on my income tax?

Tags: canada, income-tax, real-estate, capital-gain, minor

If I purchase a property in an underage dependent's name (son or daughter), and then sell it before they reach the age of majority, do I need to claim the capital gains (losses) on income tax if I already have a principal residence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've read:  In Canada, for tax purposes, a family unit (i.e. you, your spouse, and your dependent children) can only claim *one* property as **principal residence**, for the purpose of claiming the principal residence capital gains exemption.  So, you need to pick *which* property you'll be claiming as your principal residence for tax purposes, as only one home can be designated principal residence for any given year.

Therefore, I imagine that if you already have a principal residence, you would **not** be able to shelter another property from capital gains taxes simply by putting it in the name of your dependent minor – (and is that even possible?)  I would guess that gains on the sale of that additional property would be subject to capital gains tax.

Finally, if you're talking about having your dependent minor children owning real-estate, I agree with montyloree that you ought to check with a professional – it sounds potentially complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy property for an underage individual in essence you own the property, you'll be liable for capital gains.  It's best to check with a tax consultant for a more exact answer.